# Is there a way to set a timer in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

So what I want to do it start a page and if the user starts typing some input it shows that at the top of the page. But if the user stops typing input for lets say around 3 seconds it would automatically delete it.

Comment: setTimeout or setInterval - resetting on each key press ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's achievable in vanilla javascript, `setTimeout`.

`setTimeout` returns an ID, which you can use to `clearTimeout` if you don't want it to execute:

```
$(document).keyPress(function(e) {

   // do your thing

   // clear timeout that may have been set during previous key press
   window.clearTimeout(window.keyTimeout);

   window.keyTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
      // do your delete-thing
   }, 3000);

});
```